# Laravel VueJS Axios send array to controller

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, vue.js, axios

I have a laravel 5.4 application which uses VueJS 2.0 for the front end.

I'm trying to post the visitors array to the controller after populating on the page but when I return the array from the controller the data isn't there.

I can't see for the life of me what I'm doing wrong? What's interesting is if I send two visitors through I get two empty arrays returning from my controller so the number of visitors is working it's just not capturing the data.

[image]

My vue instance.

```
  <script>
    new Vue({

    el: '#app',

    data: {
        visitors: [],
        visitor: [],
    },

    methods: {
        addVisitor() {
            this.visitors.push(this.visitor);
            this.visitor = [];
        },

        storeVisit()
        {
          axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/visit/new',
            data: {
              visitors: this.visitors
            }
          });
        }
    },

});
  </script>
```

My HTML page

```
<p>Visitors</p>
    <div class="columns">
      <div class="column">
          <input class="input" placeholder="First Name" v-model="visitor.first">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
          <input class="input" placeholder="Last Name" v-model="visitor.last">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
          <input class="input" placeholder="Company" v-model="visitor.company">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
          <input class="input" placeholder="Email" v-model="visitor.email">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
          <button class="button is-primary" @click="addVisitor()">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I've then got a button that actions the storeVisit() method.

```
<button class="button is-primary" @click="storeVisit">Save Visit</button>
```

My controller waiting the post request

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->visitors;
    }
```

My response

> {"visitors":[[],[]]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`visitor` should be an object, not an array

```
data: {
    visitors: [],
    visitor: {}, // <- object here
},
```

---

```
addVisitor() {
    this.visitors.push(this.visitor);
    this.visitor = {}; // <- reset to an empty object
},
```